# HTTP Method not allowed (405) occurs on DELETE when slash in id

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is the route configuration:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{clientId}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The method signature of the controller method:

```
    // DELETE
    public void Delete(string clientId, string id)
```

Pretty much standard so far except for the id being of type string.

Everything works fine until an id contains a slash: MI-01/02

So the HTTP request looks like this:

```
DELETE http://de2sv034.xnet.oe.olympus/corporate/ExtraNet/API/dev/M01/Products/MI-01/02
```

Web-API emits HTTP-status code 405 (method not allowed). System.Uri.EscapeDataString on client side doesn't help because slash isn't escaped.

How can I get the route mapped properly even if id contains a slash?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the slash with `%2f`? It will never work on its own like that, since it's a path separator.

Comment: I just tried that with Fiddler Composer but unfortunately still 405 is emitted on server side. It seems that IIS or ASP.NET is decoding %2f back to slash before the mapping occurs.

Comment: How about if you specify it in the uri? For example: `.../Products?id="MI-01/02"` (not sure if the double quotes are required).

Comment: Yes, with id as a query parameter it works even without double quotes. So I will change the client code accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work if you specify your `id` directly inside the URI as a `query string` parameter (it doesn't even need to be URL encoded). For example, something like this in your case: `.../Products?id=MI-01/02`

It works because anything after the question mark (`?`) is no longer interpreted as part of the main path but as a query string parameter (those are separated by an ampersand `&` if you have more than one). For more information about parameter binding, see [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).